# When downloading a windows steam game over Ubuntu Wine, I get the error "content server unreachable"

Tags: wine, steam

I recently botched a dual-boot install job of windows and ubuntu, and just went full Ubuntu.

I'm trying to get my steam games to run via wine. I downloaded the latest version of Wine, and then I downloaded the latest version of the windows steam installer and ran

```
sudo wine SteamSetup.exe
```

It successfully installed steam and I can get inside, but it seems that all network features are unavilable. I can see that my friends are online, but I can't access the store. When I download my games, I get the error

```
An error occurred while installing [Game Name] (content servers are unreachable)
```

None of the tutorials I've followed have mentioned anything about this issue, and it happens whether I install Steam through the terminal, with winetricks, or with PlayOnLinux.

What's going on, here?

EDIT:

Here's the Steam developer console:

```
Failed to init SteamVR because it isn't installed
Couldn't create IPolicyConfigVista: 0x80040154
ExecCommandLine: ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\Steam.exe" -no-cef-sandbox -lognetapi -console"
IPC server is in my process - could/should be using an in process pipe
System startup time: 14.31 seconds
Crypto API failed certificate check, error flags 0x00000008 for '/C=US/ST=Massachusetts/L=Cambridge/O=Akamai Technologies, Inc./CN=a248.e.akamai.net'
Crypto API failed certificate check, error flags 0x00000008 for '/C=US/ST=Massachusetts/L=Cambridge/O=Akamai Technologies, Inc./CN=a248.e.akamai.net'
Crypto API failed certificate check, error flags 0x00000008 for '/C=US/ST=Massachusetts/L=Cambridge/O=Akamai Technologies, Inc./CN=a248.e.akamai.net'
Crypto API failed certificate check, error flags 0x00000008 for '/C=US/ST=Massachusetts/L=Cambridge/O=Akamai Technologies, Inc./CN=a248.e.akamai.net'
Crypto API failed certificate check, error flags 0x00000008 for '/C=US/ST=Massachusetts/L=Cambridge/O=Akamai Technologies, 
Inc./CN=a248.e.akamai.net'
CAPIJobRequestUserStats - Server response failed 2
"
Crypto API failed certificate check, error flags 0x00000008 for 
'/C=US/ST=Massachusetts/L=Cambridge/O=Akamai Technologies, 
Inc./CN=a248.e.akamai.net'
GameAction [AppID 8170, ActionID 1] : LaunchApp failed with AppError_18 with ""
GameAction [AppID 8170, ActionID 1] : LaunchApp changed task to Failed with ""
GameAction [AppID 8170, ActionID 2] : InstallApps waiting for user 
response to ShowEula "http://store.steampowered.com/eula/8170_eula_1"
GameAction [AppID 8170, ActionID 2] : InstallApps continues with user 
response "ShowEula"
GameAction [AppID 8170, ActionID 2] : InstallApps changed task to 
CreateNextApp with ""
saving roaming config store to 'sharedconfig.vdf'
roaming config store 2 saved successfully
GameAction [AppID 8170, ActionID 2] : InstallApps failed with 
AppError_21 with ""
```

Comment: Never heard of this problem before (That's my disclaimer) However, my understanding is wine uses winbind for networking actions. sudo apt-get install samba-common winbind I would wager that this will either fix your problem or identify a package conflict that you can troubleshoot.

Comment: Do I need to configure anything myself, or just install these programs? Simply installing these programs did not fix my issue.

Comment: any reason you do not want to dual boot? as someone that tried to run steam on linux, it was just too much trouble to setup and configure and compatibility puts too much limit when gaming on linux.

Comment: Installing should have been enough for what I was anticipating. The problem might be something beyond my skill set. Try: `systemctl status winbind` if it says the service is running then your issue is something other than what I initially thought.

Comment: Nope! It's running

Comment: I actually very much wish to dual boot, but the reason that I'm running Ubuntu exclusively is that I accidentally nuked my master boot record while trying, had to wipe the drive, and did not have a windows product key with which to reinstall.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I received a solution to my problem in the first post of this thread that I made on the wine forums:

https://forum.winehq.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=30767

Go to the link that they provide and edit the config file as specified.

> For the store not working the flag is `-no-cef-sandbox`
>
> For the content server error, a bug was filed
>   [here](https://bugs.winehq.org/show_bug.cgi?id=45329)
>
> For now there's a workaround given that requires editing a file in the
>   Steam/config directory. Comment #4 has the workaround:
>   https://bugs.winehq.org/show_bug.cgi?id=45329#c4
>
> I found out the difference between my two Steam installations - the one that works has a different config in `drive_c/Program Files/Steam/config/config.vdf`
>
> After installing Steam in a fresh WINEPREFIX, downloading games won't work. Open the mentioned config, and under:
>
> ```
> "InstallConfigStore"  
> {  
>   "Software"  
>   {  
>     "Valve"  
>     {  
>       "Steam"  
>        {
> ```
>
> add the following entry (for me it's directly under "cip" and "CM"):
>
> ```
> "CS" "valve511.steamcontent.com;valve501.steamcontent.com;valve517.steamcontent.com;valve557.steamcontent.com;valve513.steamcontent.com;valve535.steamcontent.com;valve546.steamcontent.com;valve538.steamcontent.com;valve536.steamcontent.com;valve530.steamcontent.com;valve559.steamcontent.com;valve545.steamcontent.com;valve518.steamcontent.com;valve548.steamcontent.com;valve555.steamcontent.com;valve556.steamcontent.com;valve506.steamcontent.com;valve544.steamcontent.com;valve525.steamcontent.com;valve567.steamcontent.com;valve521.steamcontent.com;valve510.steamcontent.com;valve542.steamcontent.com;valve519.steamcontent.com;valve526.steamcontent.com;valve504.steamcontent.com;valve500.steamcontent.com;valve554.steamcontent.com;valve562.steamcontent.com;valve524.steamcontent.com;valve502.steamcontent.com;valve505.steamcontent.com;valve547.steamcontent.com;valve560.steamcontent.com;valve503.steamcontent.com;valve507.steamcontent.com;valve553.steamcontent.com;valve520.steamcontent.com;valve550.steamcontent.com;valve531.steamcontent.com;valve558.steamcontent.com;valve552.steamcontent.com;valve563.steamcontent.com;valve540.steamcontent.com;valve541.steamcontent.com;valve537.steamcontent.com;valve528.steamcontent.com;valve523.steamcontent.com;valve512.steamcontent.com;valve532.steamcontent.com;valve561.steamcontent.com;valve549.steamcontent.com;valve522.steamcontent.com;valve514.steamcontent.com;valve551.steamcontent.com;valve564.steamcontent.com;valve543.steamcontent.com;valve565.steamcontent.com;valve529.steamcontent.com;valve539.steamcontent.com;valve566.steamcontent.com;valve165.steamcontent.com;valve959.steamcontent.com;valve164.steamcontent.com;valve1611.steamcontent.com;valve1601.steamcontent.com;valve1617.steamcontent.com;valve1603.steamcontent.com;valve1602.steamcontent.com;valve1610.steamcontent.com;valve1615.steamcontent.com;valve909.steamcontent.com;valve900.steamcontent.com;valve905.steamcontent.com;valve954.steamcontent.com;valve955.steamcontent.com;valve1612.steamcontent.com;valve1607.steamcontent.com;valve1608.steamcontent.com;valve1618.steamcontent.com;valve1619.steamcontent.com;valve1606.steamcontent.com;valve1605.steamcontent.com;valve1609.steamcontent.com;valve907.steamcontent.com;valve901.steamcontent.com;valve902.steamcontent.com;valve1604.steamcontent.com;valve908.steamcontent.com;valve950.steamcontent.com;valve957.steamcontent.com;valve903.steamcontent.com;valve1614.steamcontent.com;valve904.steamcontent.com;valve952.steamcontent.com;valve1616.steamcontent.com;valve1613.steamcontent.com;valve958.steamcontent.com;valve956.steamcontent.com;valve906.steamcontent.com"
> ```
>
> I don't know if the whitespace matters, here it's four tab characters
>   (0x09) "CS" two tabs and the rest, on one line. Without the ">".

Comment: This worked for me. The first time I missed the the two tabs and it didn't work. After trying with "CS" [two tabs] "xxx" it worked. So the whitespace does matter.

Comment: For me, this worked after removing content of "Accounts" section

Comment: Worked for me, but only after I restarted _both_ Steam and PlayOnLinux.

Answer (score -2):

I got this error and it turns out that a reference to the content servers was missing in the config file (`config.vdf`).

The following are the steps needed to resolve this:

1. Install a native Steam client (the official way) onto your system if you haven’t already (you really only need to do this the get that Steam clients config file).
2. Open the Steam client's config file (In my case this was located in: `/home/<username>/.steam/steam/config/config.vdf`) and look for the line starting with `CS` (this stands for “Content Server”).
3. Copy the ENTIRE line beginning with `CS` and make a note of its location in the file.
4. Open the PlayonLinux application and right-click on the Steam application and select **Open the application’s directory**.
5. Go into the `config` directory and open the `config.vdf` file.
6. Paste the `CS` line that you have just copied into a location similar to that of the config file that it was copied from (for me this was directly under `cip` and `CM`).
7. Save the file then restart your system. Once your system has rebooted you should be able to install your games using the steam client on the  PlayonLinux application.

Found in [this blog post](https://oluadebari.com/2018/06/23/playonlinux-steam-content-servers-unreachable-and-fixing-mirrors-edge-resolution-issue/).